# MYSQL count group by with a left join where there is an entry in a third table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of groups with details of groups that my users can join and a separate table of group members to show which users have joined which groups. The group_members table just has a column for group_id and a column for user_id. If there is a row with group_id = 3 AND user_id = 10 then we know user 10 is a member of group 3.

I have the following mysql statement that works well to return the details of the groups including the number of members each group has depending upon a couple of conditions in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT groups.*, COUNT(group_members.group_id) AS member_count
FROM groups LEFT JOIN
     group_members
     ON groups.group_id = group_members.group_id  
WHERE groups.deleted = 0 AND
      groups.trainer_id = ' .$trainer_id .' 
GROUP BY groups.group_id
ORDER BY groups.group_name'
```

The problem is though that users can be deleted in and aren't always removed from the group_members table when this happens. This means that users can show up in the count even though they are no longer actually in the system in a third users table.

So I want to only include group members in the count if they are also present in the users table. I thought I could do this with an INNER JOIN between the group members and users tables. Something like this...

```
SELECT groups.*, COUNT(users.user_id) AS client_count
FROM groups LEFT JOIN
     group_members
     ON groups.group_id = group_members.group_id INNER JOIN
     users
     ON group_members.user_id = users.user_id  
WHERE groups.deleted = 0 AND groups.trainer_id = ' .$trainer_id .'
GROUP BY groups.group_id
ORDER BY groups.group_name
```

The trouble with this is that when a group has no members the group is not showing up in the results. I guess because it is not able to join to the users table.

If anyone could explain to me how I can achieve what I am looking to do I'd be very grateful.

Comment: Why the down vote on the question without even a comment to explain?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LEFT JOIN` to users` should really fix your problem:

```
SELECT g.*, COUNT(u.user_id) AS client_count
FROM groups g LEFT JOIN
     group_members gm
     ON g.group_id = gm.group_id LEFT JOIN
     users u
     ON gm.user_id = u.user_id  
WHERE g.deleted = 0 AND g.trainer_id = ' .$trainer_id .'
GROUP BY g.group_id
ORDER BY g.group_name;
```

If a group is not being returned, then it does not meet the `WHERE` filtering conditions.  All groups meeting those conditions should be returned if `LEFT JOIN` is used for both joins.

I would also strongly advise you to use parameters rather than munging query strings, when you call queries from an application language.

Comment: Thank you. I actually use the Zend Framework DB adapter with it's quoteInto() method but left that out of the question for simplicity. Solid advice though.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a LEFT JOIN instead of INNER on the users table. The COUNT function skips null entries so your last query should work.

Comment: Downvote wasn't mine. I tried that but it still only returned the groups where there was at least one member

Comment: That is not what you posted. In your posted query you have one left join and one inner join. I am saying that both joins should be LEFT OUTER for it to work, and do the count on the users table, where you get the NULLs.

Comment: Also you should really review your Schema because not having a foreign key from `group_members` to `users` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: Yep, you are correct. I tried 2 left joins before and it didn't work - not sure why though as it does now. And thanks for the heads up on the foreign key. I've accepted the other answer because it has a little more details but thank you very much for your help.